# Report creator class php

Tags: php

What is the best way to call Method heDidIt() from child class Make?
I was thinking about events but couldnt find a good non global solution.

```
$control = new Control();
$maker = $control->createMaker();
$maker->doIt();

class Control
{
    private $_make;
    public function createMaker()
    {
        $this->_make = new Make();
        return $this->_make;
    }

    private function heDidIt()
    {
        //Call me if the Maker did something.
    }

}

class Make
{
    public function doIt()
    {
        //hey im doing something, better tell my Controller
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell `Make` who's its boss so it can inform him:

```
$control = new Control();
$maker = $control->createMaker();
$maker->doIt();

class Control
{
    private $_make;
    public function createMaker()
    {
        $this->_make = new Make($this);
        return $this->_make;
    }

    private function heDidIt()
    {
        //Call me if the Maker did something.
    }

    public function inform($sampleParam) {
        var_dump($sampleParam);
        $this->heDidIt();
    }
}

class Make
{
    protected $control; 

    public function __construct(Control $control) {
        $this->control = $control;
    }

    public function doIt()
    {
        //hey im doing something, better tell my Controller
        $control->inform('called in Make::doIt()');
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i will tell him who the Boss is!

Answer (score 0):

```
$control = new Control();
$maker = $control->createMaker();
$maker->doIt();

class Control
{
    private $_make;
    public function createMaker()
    {
        $this->_make = new Make();
        return $this->_make;
    }

    **protected** function heDidIt()
    {
        //Call me if the Maker did something.
    }

}

class Make **extends Control**
{
    public function doIt()
    {
        **$this -> heDidIt();**
        //hey im doing something, better tell my Controller
    }
}
```

Although this seems extremely pointless, so maybe providing your actual code and requirements would let us help you better.

Comment: What if the Control needs to know what every `Make`did?

Comment: well Make could store it in a Public variable and then Control could check that, or just a return value would also work?

Comment: the $this->_make is an array with possibly hundreds of Make instances.